# Jaspersoft Studio subtotal from amount shown on group header

Tags: jasper-reports

I have data that is "filtered" through three groups. 
First group is defined by departments, second is defined by course id and third is for individual class session id (i.e. room and schedule). Also the source query is giving me the list of all students for each class session, and this causes that the other columns get repeated for every student (i.e. credits per course, total enrollment per session, total students dropped per session, total students auditing per session, etc).

When you drop any of those query counts on the report group's footer the sum is not correct. For example if we have 10 students for a session our sum is 100 enrollment. I want to count 10 enrolled students only once.

The amounts are not shown multiple times because I placed the fields on the group header. So on every group break the row of data is displayed only once.

I believe I need a custom running total and not the default created when you drag and drop the field on the group's footer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got something working.

On the report Outline I right clicked on 'Variables' and 'Create Variable'.
For example for the audit count I did the following:

1. Named my variable 'sum_au'
2. Value Class Name set to java.math.BigDecimal
3. Calculation set to Sum
4. Expression set to the query field for the audit total 'AU': $F{AU}
5. Increment Type set to [Group]GroupBy_CRN
6. Reset Type set to [Group]GroupBy_CrseNum
7. All other fields left untouched (default values)

[image]

Once this variable is created you can drag and drop it to the CrseNum Group Footer and it will add the values only once per break on the course session id (CRN).

I will reproduce this for the other values to see if this solution is consistent...